# Thread stops updating GUI after a while

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

So I have the following running as a Thread/Task:

```
    private void _updateFunc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            //_threadHalter.WaitOne();  
            if (_func != null)
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_func);
        }
    }
```

This Thread/Task is supposed to refresh the Items belonging to a ListBox every 500 ms.  The items update just fine for about a minute, and then stop updating.  Can anyone tell me what's going on?  There are other tasks running as well.  I've tried raising the priority of the Thread, changing BeginInvoke to Invoke so that at least the Invoke will run synchronously, but none of these have alleviated what appears to be a starving of this Task.  Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thread.Sleep is a CPU intensive task. User a timer instead.

Comment: Thread.Sleep uses no CPU.  It is not a spin wait.

Comment: You need to post an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thread.Sleep does not use CPU, however if you call this from the form, it will not allow the form to process window messages and it may eventually lock up. It does seem like a Timer is better in this case.

Comment: If you're waiting for another thread to do something, there are better ways to do it.  Having said that, is your `_updateFunc` running from a `BackgroundWorker` / `Task`?

Comment: In general, BeginInvoke is something to avoid in WPF.  Prefer databinding over BeginInvoke.

Comment: In general, do NOT use a task if it never finishes. Tasks are meant to do asynchronous work and have an end.

Comment: If you want to run some code regularly after a given interval of time use a `Timer`.  It's specifically designed for that.

Comment: @reservoirman: Check the output window for any `FirstChanceException`s.  My first guess is that some exception is being 'eaten', causing it to stop updating.   Also, knowing what `_func` might be doing could be useful.

Comment: @Powerlord I've tried running it as both `Task` and `Thread`.  Thanks everybody I will try out your tips.

Comment: @user2588666 ah yes good call.  Those first chance exceptions indeed hold the key to the mystery.

Comment: @resevoirman: I'd be really interested to hear what caused it!  Glad I could help.

Comment: @user2588666 yeah it ended up being an error in the way I'm storing data in a buffer where two other threads, a producer and consumer, are accessing.  It led to a lot of first chance exceptions- primarily `System.FormatException` and `System.OverflowException`.